# Current profile section is not properly selected in narrow mode

Tags: bug, design, profile-page, responsive-design, subscription

In narrow mode (e.g. on mobile phone) if you select “Question subscription” in [profile setting page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/preferences/current) you will be redirected to the [page](https://stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=subscriptions) that is not adapted for mobile view. Going back (via browser button) will return you to profile settings page, but the current item will be still “Question subscription” (that’s wrong):

> [image]

In normal (wide) view all looks fine.